# how to access the value in MainActivity from other file in kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I have made a database in the MainActivity and I need the database instance in another class but it is giving this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
```

Here is the MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    
    val database by lazy {
        Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext,AppDatabase::class.java,"database").build()
    }

    @SuppressLint("CoroutineCreationDuringComposition")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            
        val databaseMenuItems by database.menuItemDao().getAll().observeAsState(emptyList())
            //
    }
   }
```

Here is how I am trying to access the database in file Piece.kt

```
@Composable
fun Piece(){
 
    val mainActivity = MainActivity()
    val database = mainActivity.database -> this is line where the above error is showing
    //  val databaseItems by database.menuItemDao().getAll().observeAsState(emptyList())
```

This line `val databaseItems by database.menuItemDao().getAll().observeAsState(emptyList())` returns values in the MainActivity but I want to use it in this file where it returns the null pointer exception. What can I change to make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just calling the MainActivity constructor, the way you are trying to access database is wrong. At least you should use some ViewModel to storaging your database class. But in your case you can just put the database instance in some object like this:

```
object DatabaseStorage {

    var databaseInstance: YourDatabaseClass? = null
}

class MainActivity {

    val database by lazy {
        Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext,AppDatabase::class.java,"database").build()
    }

   override fun onCreate(...) {

        DatabaseStorage.databaseInstance = database
    }
}

// and in your fun
@Composable
fun Piece() {
    val databaseInstance = DatabaseStorage.databaseInstance 
}
```

But this approach is really bad solution, you should use some DI library, and using your database directly only on data-layer. You can read this article for better solution https://proandroiddev.com/news-android-app-607f9dc6a3d1

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be passing in the database to your composable.  Standard architectural patterns would be to create a repo for your app and let the viewModel do all the connections with the database, then you can return a flow from that.

Something like:

```
class myDatabase {
     lateinit var dataBase: AppDatabase
     val dao = MyDatabaseDao()

     fun build(context: Context) {
     database = Room.databaseBuilder(context,AppDatabase::class.java,"database").build()
     }
}

class myApplication: Application { 
    override onCreate { 
        MyDatabase().build()
}

interface MyDatabaseRepo { 
    fun grabDataFromDatabase()
}

class MyDatabaseRepoImpl: MyDatabaseRepo { 
    val myDao = MyDatabase().dao

    override fun grabDataFromDatabase() { 
        myDao.doSomething()
    }
                 
}


class myViewModel(databaseRepo: MyDatabaseRepo): ViewModel() { 
    
    val myStateFlow = MutableStateFlow(listOf<Int>()) 

    fun grabData() {
       myStateFlow.update { databaseRepo.grabSomthingFromDatabase()}
    }

}

@Composable
fun Piece(viewModel:MyViewModel) { 
     val data = viewModel.myStateFlow.collectAsState()

}
```

But as Vinny said you should probably use some dependency injection to make this really clean.  This would give you lots of freedom.  I recommend koin as it is the easiest to learn.